# Simple query for getting max value for each entity

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Developing an application in C# using a MySQL database. It involves cows and their weights. When displaying the cows details in a table, I want to display all of the animal's details as well as their last weight.

I have two tables used for this: 'Cattle' and 'Weights'. Each animal has a unique ID and this ID is used as foreign key in weights table along with the date taken and what they weighed. Up to now the way I am doing it is getting the MAX(Date) in the weights table and using a left join however if animal wasn't weighed on that date then it won't be included. I could use each animals MAX(Weight) however some animals may drop in weight due to illness etc.

```
SELECT Cattle.TagNumber,
       Cattle.HerdNumber,
       Cattle.Breed,
       Cattle.DOB,
       Cattle.Group,
       Weights.Weight
FROM Cattle
LEFT JOIN Weights ON Cattle.TagNumber = Weights.TagNumber
WHERE Cattle.Group = '" + group + "'
AND Date = '" + date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "'";
```

The above query is what I use when filtering the data by the animals group. I understand that I could go through each animal individually and get their MAX(Weight) however this severely hinders the performance.

Comment: **Don't concatenate queries with data, use a proper parameterized query** What happens if `group` is `' TRUNCATE TABLE Cattle; /*`?

Comment: Yes I agree. Changing all my queries to parameterised ones at the moments after learning of SQL injection hacks. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Why is the weight in a separate table?  Or is there something not shown in that query?

Comment: Each animal can have more than one weight so the weights are held in another table along with the animal number and date taken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select for the Max(Date) found on the join, instead of searching a specific Date (Where clause), you will always get the results. Not exactly sure if this is what is asked.

```
SELECT Cattle.TagNumber,
       Cattle.HerdNumber,
       Cattle.Breed,
       Cattle.DOB,
       Cattle.Group,
       Weights.Weight,
       MAX(Date)
FROM Cattle
LEFT JOIN Weights ON Cattle.TagNumber = Weights.TagNumber
WHERE Cattle.Group = '" + group + "'
Group by Cattle.TagNumber;
```

**Edit**

The query should also return values with no weights; you just need to filter the data. You can use Case (it might not work exactly as I wrote it, but something around that). There was the `End` missing; also you probably need to convert weight to a nvarchar (or what you chose), otherwise you will get an error when inserting `weight` in the column `NAMECOLUMN`

```
SELECT Cattle.TagNumber,
       Cattle.HerdNumber,
       Cattle.Breed,
       Cattle.DOB,
       Cattle.Group,
       (Case when Weights.Weight is null then 'N/A' Else Convert(nvarchar(max),Weights.Weight) End) as NAMECOLUMN,    
       MAX(Date)
FROM Cattle
LEFT JOIN Weights ON Cattle.TagNumber = Weights.TagNumber
WHERE Cattle.Group = '" + group + "'
Group by Cattle.TagNumber;
```

Comment: Yeah that looks good. However, how could I also include animals that perhaps don’t have any weights at all? And just output “N/A” or something similar?

Comment: Answer was edited. Just realized when I edit an answer, others will not be notified

Comment: Just tried the query and I get the following error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') as NAME_Column),
       MAX(Date)
FROM Cattle
LEFT JOIN Weights ON Cattl...' at line 6

Comment: there's an extra Parenthesis

Comment: Yeah I assumed that was the issue too however the problem still occurs when I removed the parenthesis. Is there a different way to write the CASE line?

Comment: Done. Was writing code on the broswer so `end` was missing. Also, check edited section to see the use convert function (which you probably need)

Comment: Got it working. There was an error with the convert but works fine without. Thanks so much!

Comment: After checking over the results, I have noticed that it outputs the MAX(Date) but not the MAX(Weight). This is because I took out the convert section that included the (max) bit. I have tried to get MAX(Weight) without the convert but haven't been successful. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You Said you wanted the last weight, so that's why se used Max(date).  The convert is there because you are assigning either a varchar ('N/A') or a number (I suppose weight is a number of some sort). If you don't convert it Will give you an error. If you want the Max(weight) instead, drop the Max(Date) (you can substitute ir for date, and it Will return you the date of Max(weight). PS: you can't haver both Max(Date) and Max(Weight); it makes no sense if you think about it

Comment: Sorry I didn’t mean to say MAX(Weight) what I meant was that the weight shown wasn’t the weight that was associated with MAX(Date) it just shows the first weight for that animal. It should show the weight with the date value equal to MAX(Date). I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Assuming Date is on table Weight: We are using an aggregating function (Max(Date)) to return the row with Max(Date) (including the corresponding weight). It shouldn't return the last inserted value. Please check the data, if it is indeed incorrect, provide a code example with the query +data please.